# Copying structure in C

Tags: c, struct

I have a problem with copying structure to another.. soo shall u help me :)
I want to write out youngest person,,

```
# include <stdio.h>

# include <string.h>

struct person {
    char name[16], surname[21];
    int age;
};

int main (){
    struct person x[3], min;
    int i, min_element;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        gets(x[i].name);
        gets(x[i].surname);
        scanf("%d", &x[i].age);
        fflush(stdin);
    }
    min_element=x[0].age;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        if(min_element>x[i].age)
            min=x[i]; // here i want to copy structure 
    }
    puts(min.name);
    puts(min.surname);
    printf("%d", min.age);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for that... but another problem is text on screen.. it is like:
F☻
bô!s
2686740

Comment: "A problem"? Could you be a bit more precise about what's not working?

Comment: you could've got help from `google` there are many solutions, and don't use `gets` it's depricated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably that you are not changing min_element when you find a lower element, so you're always testing against x[0].age. You probably want to do:

```
if (x[i].age < min_element) {
    min = x[i];
    min_element = x[i].age;
}
```

For copying structures, you can also use `memcpy`

```
memcpy(&min, &x[i], sizeof(min));
```

http://linux.die.net/man/3/memcpy

Which would make the code

```
if (x[i].age < min_element) {
    memcpy(&min, &x[i], sizeof(min));
    min_element = x[i].age;
}
```

Comment: If the struct has member that's a dynamic array, will `memcpy` only copy the pointer?

Comment: Yes, but so would `min = x[i];`. This is C, not C++.

Answer (score 2):

Your structures have value semantics, i.e. they don't have pointers, so copying by value will do the right thing, so you can simply say:

```
myperson1 = myperson2;
```

Comment: that's what he's doing right now

Comment: @LihO: That doesn't mean that the answer is bad, only that the question is silly.

Answer (score 0):

Since your structure contains plain data only, your copying is perfectly valid and reasonable:

```
min=x[i];
```

where both `x[i]` and `min` are of type `struct person`. However you seem to have an error in your logic. If you want to find structure with the minimum `age`, try:

```
min_element=x[0].age;
for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    if(min_element > x[i].age) {
        min=x[i];
        min_element = min.age;      // <-- update new minimum
    }
}
```

Also note that `gets` is quite dangerous and pretty much "deprecated", use `fgets` or `scanf` instead:

```
scanf("%15s", x[i].name);
scanf("%20s", x[i].surname);
```